# Disabling or overriding the excel and pdf export function in Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server-2005, excel, reporting-services, export

Is there a way to disable or override the excel and pdf export function in SQL Server Reporting Services. I want to my own custom excel export.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable them, you can edit the ReportServer RSReportServer.Config file.  Remove the Excel and PDF extensions from the Render section.

More Info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627537.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Locate the file name `RSReportDesigner.config` at

> "Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\RSReportDesigner.config".

then add `visible = false`
Your PDF export will not be visible in report server